# An error was encountered while processing the request from the application

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

We are blocking with a popup alert with error message in the question title

> An error was encountered while processing the request from the
>   application.

This error seems to appear since I deploy a new `.war` file to the MF runtime and then I roll-back everything (in the past two months the app is running very well and never stucks with this error) but it still remains.

**What did I try:**

1.the app is working fine in preview mode in my local PC;

2.in iPhone I just can change the MF server connectivity url to my local PC and it works fine, too (but with error when it connected with the production environment url);

3.all codes which has a possibility to make this error are roll-back and then I re-deploy the war file but still bad;

4.googled and get this page:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM93835 but in my case nothing changed in `application-descriptor.xml`

5.got the same error message with this guy ([Worklight Authenticity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033111/worklight-authenticity), [unknown challenge arrived, cannot process realm wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975181/unknown-challenge-arrived-cannot-process-realm-wl-devicenoprovisioningrealm-cha)) but what he does did not fix my error, too.

**Tommat related error log:**

```
Sep 07, 2015 8:17:41 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest
SEVERE: FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'wl_authenticityLoginModule' failed. Missing app authenticity configuration parameters. [project worklight]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Missing app authenticity configuration parameters
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.appauth.AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.java:24)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.AuthenticityAuthenticator.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticator.java:79)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:209)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:713)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:613)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:586)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:501)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:155)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 07, 2015 8:17:41 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest
SEVERE: FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule wl_authenticityLoginModule, User Identity {wl_directUpdateRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule), SubscribeServlet=null, SingleStepAuthRealm=(name:1195, loginModule:AuthLoginModule), wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLRemoteDisableNullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:72v8umn1isngnia7hbccnhqs3u, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:BF8A1B93-0D28-4488-A2FB-226629FDA1C6, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:1195, loginModule:AuthLoginModule), wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:97a5962b-1262-4891-8d4a-43699388f91b, loginModule:WeakDummy)}. [project worklight] [project worklight]
Sep 07, 2015 8:17:41 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest
SEVERE: FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'wl_authenticityLoginModule' failed. Missing app authenticity configuration parameters. [project worklight]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Missing app authenticity configuration parameters
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.appauth.AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.java:24)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.AuthenticityAuthenticator.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticator.java:79)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:209)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:713)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:613)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:586)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:501)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:155)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 07, 2015 8:17:41 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest
SEVERE: FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule wl_authenticityLoginModule, User Identity {wl_directUpdateRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule), SubscribeServlet=null, SingleStepAuthRealm=(name:1195, loginModule:AuthLoginModule), wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLRemoteDisableNullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:72v8umn1isngnia7hbccnhqs3u, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:BF8A1B93-0D28-4488-A2FB-226629FDA1C6, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:1195, loginModule:AuthLoginModule), wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:97a5962b-1262-4891-8d4a-43699388f91b, loginModule:WeakDummy)}. [project worklight] [project worklight]
```

**some parts of The `authenticationConfig.xml` file** (in fact nothing changed in this file since two months ago):

```
*** ***
    <customSecurityTest name="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"  step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>   

</securityTests> 

<realms>
    <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="SingleStepAuthRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="LoginHTTPAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="LoginHTTPAdapter.onLogout"/>
    </realm>
    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>
*** ***
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the error log, remove `wl_authenticityRealm` from the `authenticationConfig.xml` makes it working alright.

Answer (score 0):

The error message relates to the Application Authenticity Protection feature.
This failure will occur if the application fails to correctly respond to the authenticity challenge that is sent to it once it attempts to connect to the MobileFirst Server.

You must make sure that you properly configured the server and app by following the instructions provided in the following tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

After you have followed the instructions, the updated .war file must be deployed to the server.

In a development environment this is irrelevant - Application Authenticity Protection is available only in remote servers (QA/UAT/Production, etc...) and not in the development server in Eclipse.

This is your only course of action. You must make sure that you have properly configured it, and then deploy the updated .war, .wlapp to the server and the app to the device.

Comment: IMO the only thing I can do to **properly configured** Application Authenticity Protection is to properly editing the `authenticationConfig.xml`, at least in the file level, right? Nothing changed in other configuration files since the error occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. authenticationConfig.xml is a file that is inserted to the .war file after build. If you change this file, you must re-deploy the .war file; In this file you either add the authenticity security test or remove it. But that's not enough, you then need to configure application-descriptor.xml per the tutorial. These changes are also part of the .war file. You must re-deploy.